# Unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning Objective-C and just trying out some sample code. I am getting the following error message:

```
unrecognized selector sent to class
```

Here is my code.

Basics.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Fraction.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Fraction *myFraction; 

    // Create an instance of a Fraction

    myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
    myFraction = [Fraction init];

    // set Fraction to 1/3
    [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
    [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

    // Display the value using the print method
    NSLog(@"The value of myFraction is:");
    [myFraction print];
    [myFraction release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Fraction.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// -- interface section --//
@interface Fraction : NSObject {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

// public method signatures
-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
@end
```

Fraction.m

```
//--implementation section --//
@implementation Fraction 
-(void) print 
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i",numerator,denominator);
}
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
    numerator = n;
}
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d
{
    denominator = d;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`alloc` is a class method, but `init` is an instance method. In your code, the compiler is complaining that it can't find any class method named `init`, which is accurate. To correct this, you should call `init` upon the instance you received back from `alloc`, like so:

```
myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
myFraction = [myFraction init];
```

but the most common pattern is to nest the calls like this:

```
// calls -init on the object returned by +alloc
myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
```

This also helps you avoid errors that might occur by calling methods on an object that has been allocated, but not yet initialized.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what has been said regarding the nested `alloc` / `init` call, something you may be interested in is `description`. In your `Fraction` class implementation, add a method like this:

```
 - (NSString *) description
{
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator];
}
```

Now, you can use it directly in `NSLog` statements like this:

```
// set Fraction to 1/3
[myFraction setNumerator: 1];
[myFraction setDenominator: 3];

// Display the value using the print method
NSLog(@"The value of myFraction is: %@", myFraction);
```

Comment: I believe that specific Fraction class is from a Big Nerd Ranch book on Objective-C, so that's probably going to come up eventually.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer was awhile ago so I wanted to give a little update. If you are using `alloc`/`init` to initialize you can shorten it to just

`[Fraction new]`

and that will be equivalent.